# How to install packages offline?

Tags: 64-bit, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

I googled and found keryx- http://keryxproject.org/ but it does not support ubuntu 10.10 x64. Is there other way to install packages on Ibuntu 10.10 64 bit offline?