# Where does Ubuntu store install files?

Tags: installation, backup

When I download a package from Synaptic, where does Ubuntu store the install files, if at all? Bandwidth is limited in my country, and I would like to download programs only once and back them up for future use.

Comment: @Hernan good place to start -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/15672/how-to-install-packages-offline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packages are stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. I suggest using [APTonCD](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/)

```
sudo apt-get install aptoncd
```

for backing them up to a CD or DVD. You can then use this disk as an offline repository.

Comment: Note that the cache is frequently cleaned up, so if you plan to use the cache, you ought to increase the cache size (I couldn't find out quickly how to do that).

Comment: You could change the settings here sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20archive by setting the MaxAge and MaxSize variables http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1136793